# HC-05 will NOT pair in Master mode (AT+ROLE=1). Same module will pair in slave mode (AT+ROLE=0)

Tags: hc-05

I have a HC-05 Bluetooth module Version (+VERSION:2.0-20100601).
I am using Linux Mint Rosa on an Acer laptop

**Section 1 - How it's wired**
Wiring

```
HC-05       Arduino
VCC         5V
GND         GND
TX          pin 1
RX          GND via voltage divider (GND to 2k resistor{2k to HC-05 RX and a 1k resistor} 1k to pin 0)
```

**Section 2 - Sequence to get into AT command state**
The sequence I use to get the BT module in AT command state

- Unplug the Arduino Uno
- Unplug both the RX and TX
- Press the button on the HC-05
- Plug in the Arduino
- HC-05 LED flashes 1 time every 2 seconds
- Initialize com ports via Linux terminal - sudo chmod 0777 /dev/ttyACM*
- Upload an empty sketch
- Plug in the HC-05 RX to Arduino pin 0, and TX to pin 1
- Open the Serial monitor
- Set Both NL & CR  and 38400 baud

**Section 3 - AT commands issued**
I use the following AT commands with the noted results.

```
AT                                  > OK
AT+ORGL                             > OK
AT+RMAAD                            > OK
AT+VERSION  +VERSION:2.0-20100601   > OK
AT+ADDR     +ADDR:98d3:b1:fd85b0    > OK
AT+NAME=Master1                     > OK
AT+UART  +UART:38400,0,0            > OK
AT+ROLE  +ROLE:0                    > OK
```

NOTE:HC-05 is set to slave and it will pair (see Section 4 below)

THE PROBLEM IS AFTER PAIRING, I RETURN TO AT COMMAND MODE (Section 2) and SET ROLE=1 (Section 5) BUT IT WILL NOT PAIR IN MASTER MODE.

**Section 4 - Pairing**
I do the following to pair the HC-05 to my phone

- Unplug the Arduino
- Plug the Arduino back in
- HC-05 LED flashes quickly blink/blink/blink
- Android phone>settings>connections>Bluetooth>Scan
- 1 device found > Master1 > pair 1234
- Android app > Serial BT terminal>device>Master1>connected
- Once Android app connects:
- HC-05 LED flashes blink/blink 2 seconds then blink/blink
- Remove the RX and TX cables from Arduino and put a jumper to connect HC-05 TX to RX (loopback)
- Serial BT terminal>hello>send
- Output both green and blue - which means the data was sent via RX and returned via TX.

**Section 5 - change ROLE=0 (slave) to ROLE=1 (Master)**
I then follow the same sequence that I used previously in Section 2 to return to AT command state.

Issue the following AT commands

```
AT                      > OK
AT+ROLE  +ROLE:0        > OK
AT+ROLE=1               > OK
```

Since I changed the configuration I unpair the device on my phone.
I then follow the same sequence that I previously used in Section 4 to pair the HC-05 to my phone

- HC-05 LED flashes quickly blink/blink/blink
- Android phone>settings>connections>Bluetooth>Scan - CAN'T FIND THE DEVICE.

If I return to AT Command mode and change AT+ROLE=0 it will Pair.

In Master mode:

- I tried to swap the TX and RX pins - won't pair.
- I tried to pair with the TX and RX removed from the Arduino - won't pair.
- I tried NOT UNpairing the device on the phone but it won't communicate with it via the android app once I change it to Master (Section 5).
- As I mentioned above if I return to AT Command mode and change AT+ROLE=0 it will Pair.

Lastly I have 2 other HC-05 modules and they all fail to pair when set to Master mode, so I'm thinking I'm missing something but can't figure out what it is.

I would appreciate hearing from anyone with the same problem and anyone who can determine what I'm doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You might have already solved your problem, but I just wanted to say that a HC-05 Blueooth module will only connect to a phone when it is in slave mode. The phone acts like a master, and therefore, it can't connect to another master.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that these device do very well in slave more, however, in Master mode, they only connect to themselves ( I mean other HC-05).
I have sevceral slave devices ( gamepads, GPS modules, ...)  that never get connected, thoug the HC-05 sees them through the INQ  command, & accurately returns their address, class, signal force, and their name even.
Though, I never succeeded to pair them !!
As if they were designed to be used together and never tested with other slave devices !!?

Comment: Not an answer...